# PHP not connecting to my database on Linux?

Tags: linux, php, database, mariadb

I use mariadb as my database and phpmyadmin to access on databases web on Linux. Although I am able to connect to the database on the commandline as root but cannot check connection to the database with PHP? I am unsure  if there's something I'm missing out?

**My HTML/PHP Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
        <?php
        $host = 'localhost';
        $user = root';
        $password = '';
        $db = 'testdb';

        $dbconnect=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);

        if ($dbconnect->connect_error) {
                die("Database connection failed.");
        }

        ?>

</body>
</html>
```

**What my web page displays:**

"connect_error) { die("Database connection failed: " . $dbconnect->connect_error); } ?> "

**What I've tried:**

- Changing to `bind-address 0.0.0.0`.
- Allowing the `port 3306` through
  firewall.

Still the same display.

Comment: You have a problem in your PHP Syntax `$user = root';` is missing a quotation mark.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the PHP issue, there is a mire fundamental issue here.

There are different MySQL authentication methods that can be used. Relevant ones here are:

- Username / password
- Socket authentication

MySQL is often configured so that it uses socket authentication for `root` user. In this case it means, the command line tool uses a UNIX domain socket to connect to the server and the server can check who is connecting by checking the user at the other end of socket.

This means that only processes running as `root` can connect to the MySQL server via UNIX domain socket.

Your web server is running under another user, so it cannot use the `root` account. Therefore you must create another user/password for your web server / PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: How do you do the socket authentication?

Comment: You shouldn't use socket authentication with web applications. You need to create separate user for your web application with MySQL command line tool.

Comment: Created user, Granted privileges but my page is blank white? How do I check that mysql is working with localhost?

Comment: Your example PHP code connects to database. If the connection is succesful, it doesn't display anything extra. You need to add more to your PHP code to actually see something.

Comment: Ah right I see what you mean. I'll try that.

Comment: Can't seem to retrieve data from the database. I created errors to see if any error response appears but none

Answer (score 0):

Once you have fixed your syntax error in `$user = root';`...

From MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  [4.2.4 Connecting to the MySQL Server Using Command Options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting.html):

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name `localhost` specially, in
> a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other
> network-based programs: the client connects using a Unix socket file.
> The `--socket` option or the `MYSQL_UNIX_PORT` environment variable
> may be used to specify the socket name.

As PHP doesn't do that, the MySQL server cannot determine the user. Therefore, you must use password authentication. Also, for the sake of security, please don't do this as the root!

Comment: I fixed the syntax error and looked at the reference manual. Tired to perform the commands from there just comes up as syntax errors.

Although there's no code error displaying but the page is blank now.

I used root because I was trying to get the PHP to communicate with my database server. I also tried ""testuser" same problem.